# value not display correctly in textbox populate value in second textbox based on the value selected in first textbox by using jquery and ajax in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am working on a small form in mvc3 with 2 fields 1 is for account code and second is for account description.
i get data of account code and description from sql server 2008 r2 database in account code field with jquery autocomplete textbox but it does not display values coreectly in text boxes.
below is my code.

```
$(function () {
        $("#AcCode").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/AutocompleteSuggestions", type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.split('-')[0], value: item.split('-')[1] }
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            minLength: 1,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item) {
                    alert("You picked" + ui.item.label + "' with a value of " + ui.item.value);
                     $("#AcCode").val(ui.item.label),
                   $("#Descrip").val(ui.item.value);
                }
            }

        });
    });
```

it display description in account code field and nothing display in description field.
 help me to solve this problem. i want to display descripton in description field and account code in account code field.

function  to get data from database 
      public List GetAutoCompDataDAL(string Acode)
        {

```
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select AcCode,Descrip from Account where AcCode like '%'+@AcCode+'%' order by AcCode asc", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AcCode", Acode);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {

                    result.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}", dr["AcCode"].ToString(), dr["Descrip"].ToString()));


                }
                con.Close();
                return result;
                //return result1;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why did you concatenate the string only to split it afterwards? Would be easier for you if you just return it as a json object with two fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a viewmodel (option #1) that can represent `AcCode` and `Descrip` or if you don't want that extra code (additional class) then return a list of objects (option #2):

```
// option #1 if you want a viewmodel
public class AccountModel {
    public string Code {get;set}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
// then use it just like the following:
//
// instead of this
// List<string> result = new List<string>();
// do this:
// option #1
// var results = new List<AccountModel>();
// option #2 
var results = new List<object>();

while (dr.Read())
{
    var code = dr["AcCode"].ToString();
    var desc = dr["Descrip"].ToString();
    results.Add(new { code , desc });
}
```

Then after your last `using` clause return the `results` object as a json:

```
public ActionResult AutocompleteSuggestions() {
    return Json(results,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And then instead of doing:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/checkout/AutocompleteSuggestions", type: "POST", dataType: "json",
    data: { term: request.term },
    success: function (data) {
        response($.map(data, function (item) {
            return { label: item.split('-')[0], value: item.split('-')[1] }
        }))
    }
})
```

you can refer to each field:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/checkout/AutocompleteSuggestions", type: "POST", dataType: "json",
    data: { term: request.term },
    success: function (data) {
        response($.map(data, function (item) {
            return { label: item.code, value: item.desc }
        }))
    }
})
```

Comment: i have used option 2 but still my autocomplete function returns description in both fields not the account code in account code field. whats the problem here? plz guide me

Comment: I have copied over your example to my answer and made the necessary changes. Are you sure you are using the right item field?

Comment: i checked it in firebug it display firstly exact values but after exit from this function it display description value in both text boxes. it change the value when it goes into jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js file.